# Are comments 100% safe on all the major environments?

Tags: javascript, syntax, comments

Are comments literally just stripped out of your source before parsing, or can they count as linebreaks and disrupt continuity in certain contexts?

```
'foo'.replace(/f/, 'b') //f->b
     .replace(/o/, 'a') //o->a
     .replace(/o/, 'r') /*o->r*/ ;

'foo'.replace(/x/, /*matches "x"*/ 'y');

var foo = ( true !== false ) ? // bikeshed
          'bar' : /*if they're equal, which they won't be, we'll want 'baz'*/ 'baz';
```

You know, cause they say whitespace is "safe" and "insignificant" or whatever, but we all know there are exceptions to that.  Are comments *actually* safe?

Comment: I guess so, unless there are parsing errors int the compiler/parser you're using..

Comment: Epic question, which means it's been asked before. Has it?

Comment: Whatever SO markdown syntax highlighter is doing is what will happen

Comment: @qwertymk WTF are you basing that on?

Comment: See also [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12659275/1597180)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're ignored *during* parsing, if they were stripped out before parsing, the parser would need to scan the input twice.

> However, the LineTerminator at the end of the line is not considered
>   to be part of the single-line comment; it is recognised separately by
>   the lexical grammar and becomes part of the stream of input elements
>   for the syntactic grammar. This point is very important, because it
>   implies that the presence or absence of single-line comments does not
>   affect the process of automatic semicolon insertion

[ES5 Specification for comments](http://es5.github.com/#x7.4).

The source code is tokenised as if the comments didn't exist.

Comment: Is `abc/* A comment */def` one identifier (`abcdef`) or two (`abc` followed by `def`)?

Comment: @adlwalrus Read the [language specification for comments](http://es5.github.com/#x7.4).

Comment: @alex, He doesn't care about the spec, he's only interested in browser's implementation of it, apparently.

Comment: @Brad And what did you use to determine that?

Comment: @alex, That's my read anyway... based on the title of the question.  I could be wrong.

Comment: @alex, Never mind, turns out he was interested in the spec.  :-)

Comment: IDK, I was just interested in informative discussion. Citing the spec is cool, experiential knowledge of incidental implementations is also cool, probably better in the case of this question.

Comment: @adlwalrus Yes, the `\n` is preserved for the sake of ASI's rules.

Comment: @j_random_hacker `var f/*oo*/oo = 'foo';

console.log(foo);` doesn't work.

Comment: @alex why does `var f/*oo*/oo = 'foo';

console.log(foo);` result in a `SyntaxError`, then?

Comment: @adlwalrus: Thanks, though if Javascript is anything like C++, relying on an interpreter/compiler to "get it right" is asking for trouble :) In C++ the rule is that comments turn into single spaces. A similar corner case would be `x+/* Comment */+;`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, comments are safe.

(That being said, I've seen some broken server-side HTML minifiers that don't know what inline JavaScript is, and removes all of the line breaks.  A comment beginning with `//` comments out the entire script.)

Comment: I'll accept this in 10 mins or whatever if you can cite any kind of source.

Comment: @adlwalrus, My source is that in 15 years, I haven't seen a browser screw up JavaScript comments.  If you don't want to trust that, then fine.  Alex's answer is a better one anyway, with his explanation.

Comment: @adlwalrus, If you want the spec:  http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.4

Comment: That's a perfectly fine source in my book, and I'm 100% willing to trust it. I just wanted to know what you were basing it on.

Comment: Have some upvotes for being so humble as to suggest I accept someone elses.  I suppose that at 29.3k rep, shortage of points has long ceased to be a source of frustration, and the pettiness goes away? :P Also, upboated for spec link.

Comment: @adlwalrus, You shouldn't go through and upvote answers, unless you found them useful to you.  Besides, they will automatically be removed anyway.  Only vote for what you find useful to you.

Comment: Oh, haha. How will they be removed?

Comment: @adlwalrus, There is a bot that goes around and looks at timestamps and what not to remove voting that seems suspicious.  You can ask about it over on the meta site, if you are interested.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Didnd't know that Stack had bots.