# If comments are safe, then why doesn't `x = 0; x+/*cmt*/+;` or `var f/*cmt*/oo = 'foo';` work?

Tags: javascript, syntax, comments

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659020/are-comments-100-safe-on-all-the-major-environments/12659032#comment17078409_12659032) thread inspired the question.  Here are the code samples again.  I'm looking for an answer that tells exactly what is going on.

Both `x = 0; x+/*cmt*/+;` and `var f/*cmt*/oo = 'foo';`  produce syntax errors, which renders the answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12659020/1597180) question wrong.

Comment: Why would you want to put comments there anyway?

Comment: Just because a comment isn't read, doesn't mean the parser will concatenate the strings and turn it into a valid statement.

Comment: You can do this: `x /* this is a comment */ ++;`, I think, but not like yours.

Comment: Just intellectual masturbation. No other reason.

Comment: @AlvinWong tested `x = 0; x /* this is a comment */ ++;`, works.

Comment: Like when you write a sentence, you can bracket some comments between words, but not inside words.

Comment: @dystroy Here is the [reference](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.4)

Comment: The section I linked to talks about comments, and below that are the various tokens. As the input is split up into _tokens_, the lexical analysis doesn't result in a valid _statement_, which is why you get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [ECMAScript reference](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.4) :

> Comments **behave like white space** and are discarded except that, if a
>   MultiLineComment contains a line terminator character, then the entire
>   comment is considered to be a LineTerminator for purposes of parsing
>   by the syntactic grammar.

Comment: This is like musical acceptance.  I've decided to come to rest on this answer, but check out the rest of the thread, as well.  It's greatly informative.

Answer (score 8):

You're interrupting a word instead of a sentence. ++ and foo are words. People assume you won't be interrupting those.

Much the same as you can't put whitespace in the middle of words even though whitespace is "safe".

Comment: Can you give me a clearer idea of what constitutes a "word" and what consitutes a "sentence", then?

Comment: @adlwalrus the comment is just like whitespace. Look `x = 0; x+/*cmt*/+;` is an error because `x = 0; x+ +;` is an error.

Comment: Comment is a *different* type of token than identifiers, operators and literal constants, so it is similar to whitespace.

Answer (score 5):

Because comments are parsed at the [lexical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) level, generally considered as whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

When compiling, the first step is to lexically break it up into individual **tokens.** Comments are one type of token, and operators are another. You're splitting the ++ operator token so that it's interpretted as two separate items.

Answer (score 1):

As many others have pointed out, the lexical parsing determines how things will become.

Let me point out some example:

```
ax + ay - 0x01; /* hello */
^----^---------------------- Identifier (variables)
   ^----^------------------- Operator
          ^----------------- literal constant (int)
              ^------------- Statement separator
  ^-^--^-^---  ^------------ Whitespace (ignored)
                [_________]- Comments (ignored)
```

So the resulting token list will be:

```
identifier("ax");
operator("+");
identifier("ay");
operator("-");
const((int)0x01);
separator();
```

But if you do this:

```
a/* hello */x + ay - 0x01;
^-----------^---^----------- Identifier (variables)
              ^----^-------- Operator
                     ^------ literal constant (int)
                         ^-- Statement separator
             ^-^--^-^------- Whitespace (ignored)
 [_________]---------------- Comments (ignored)
```

The resulting token list will be:

```
identifier("a");
identifier("x"); // Error: Unexpected identifier `x` at line whatever
operator("+");
identifier("ay");
operator("-");
const((int)0x01);
separator();
```

Then same happens when comments inserted inside an operator.

So you can see that comments behave just like whitespace.

In fact, I recently just read an article on writing a simple interpreter with JavaScript. It helped me with this answer. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/345888/How-to-write-a-simple-interpreter-in-JavaScript

Comment: That article link looks awesome! This whole thread is fantastic, I wish I could "accept" multiple answers.